# Is it possible to have a Python script run from anywhere else than the Windows shell?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

I'm running a script that involves a lot of foreign characters, and the classic cmd line seems to choke on them, which might be related to my Windows setup. It runs fine in IDLE and other IDE's. Is there anyway that I can launch my script automatically from another place (e.g. IDLE) without first having to open another program?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a shortcut of the form:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\location\of\your\script.py"
```

Obviously substitute your version of Python.  If you include arguments that also point to a file that contains your foreign characters, you can have it load that as well.

To have the command windows stay open, use one of the following at the end of your script:

```
# Python 2
raw_input()

# Python 3
input()
```

Comment: My script produces output that I need to see, so that isn't an option.

Comment: Updated to handle your clarification.  Changed pythonw to python so it creates a command window.